# Can I still access my s3 object when i have enabled encryption on it, but the encryption has not completed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Given:

- Bucket "alpha", no default encryption
- Object "bravo" in "alpha", no encryption enabled

I then enable encryption on bravo, and lets assume its a large file so the process of encrypting it may take minutes.

What happens if i attempt to access bravo during the window of time in which bravo is being encrypted??
During the encryption process, is unencrypted bravo still accessible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encrypting an object involves copying an object on top of itself, with the new copy being encrypted.  This is an atomic operation, so the unencrypted version of the object remains in place and accessible until the copy operation is complete.

This also happens much more quickly than the question implies.

Comment: Click the checkmark under the voting buttons.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer